# Query children of a Datastore entity

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I query all the children of a `Datastore` entity in `Python`? The parent entity is of a different kind, but all children are of the same kind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
ChildKind.all().ancestor(parent).fetch(100)
```

Comment: Thanks very much Nick. I somehow managed not to find the `ancestor()` method in the docs.